# Specific Predictions (Binary) in R

Tags: r, classification, prediction, dataset, binary-data

I want to make two new predictions (based on two new data frames).

**What I did:**

- First of all (obvious) splitting the data: train / test
- Secondly: train my model (and evaluate it on my test set)

**Now the interesting part jumps in:**

- I took my test set, and filtered it on specific values (let's say I have a column called Facebook. I filtered the test set on Facebook == 1.
- I did the same for the column Instagram. So let's say another data set with Instagram == 1.

Because I have plenty of columns (+50), I thought that it was the right approach to simple filter the test set on the specific columns (and safe them as a new data frame). **But is this a valid approach?** (making new data frames to predict, based on my test set).

And could I say, if my precision and recall are both >.90 and accuracy = 92% on my test set, that I can predict (the two new data frames) with an accuracy of 92%?

For the interested people, my code (the prediction part)

```
# model = my model 

set.seed(123)
facebook_data <- test_set 
facebook_data <- filter(facebook_data , facebook == 1)

predictions_facebook <- predict(model, facebook_data) 
confusionMatrix (predictions_facebook, facebook_data$target)

set.seed(123)
instagram_data <- test_set 
instagram_data <- filter(instagram_data , instagram == 1)

predictions_instagram <- predict(model, instagram_data ) 
confusionMatrix (predictions_instagram, instagram_data $target)
```